# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:

Tags: angularjs, spring-4

I have a list of 'startDate and 'endDate' which is passed to the controller through $http Post request, but it is throwing the error as mentioned in the subject.My code as below

```
$scope.saveUpdateAnualAudit=function(auditPlanLst)
    {
        $scope.auditCycleLst = [];
        $scope.auditCycleLst = JSON.stringify(auditPlanLst); 
    //auditPlanLst is a list of startDate and endDate captured from the view
        console.log("$scope.auditCycleLst "+$scope.auditCycleLst);          
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "PlanAuditController/saveUpdateAnualAudit/"+$scope.auditCycleLst,         

          }).success(function(data, status) {             
          })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.errorMsg= "<strong>Error!</strong> Failed to retrieve AuditPlan of .";
                $scope.showErrorAlert = true;
                $scope.showSuccessAlert = false;
              });
    }

}]);
```

Controller code as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUpdateAnualAudit/{auditCycleLst}", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String saveUpdateAnualAudit(@RequestBody List<AuditCycleJsonVo> auditCycleLst) {     
        try {
            System.out.println("Saved to db");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
        return "planAudits";    
    }
```

where AuditCycleJsonVo class is as below

```
public class AuditCycleJsonVo {
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

}
```

I am not able to locate where is it going wrong by the error it is throwing, it does not come to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send the auditCycleList as a **RequestBody** param, as the controller is expecting :

You could build the request like this:

```
var req = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'PlanAuditController/saveUpdateAnualAudit',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': "application/json"
   },
   data: $scope.auditCycleLst
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```